# Exception: Failed to retrieve form data. Please wait and try again

Tags: google-apps-script, exception, async-await, triggers, google-forms

I have been getting this error a lot lately due to which my customer thinks this is a bug from my end but it issue from Google's end.
`const respondentEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();`, is where it is giving me an error, can someone help me solve this issue as I'm not able to find any on internet

```
async function onFormSubmit(e) {
Logger.log("Inside On Form Submit");
const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
let latestFormResponse;
const formResponses = form.getResponses();
const respondentEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
if (respondentEmail === "") return false 

///.. other code
}
```

[image]

can anyone please help me out? I'm loosing customers due to this bug :(

Comment: Could you give some reproduction steps of how to get this exception and show a screenshot of where / how you see this exception?

Comment: This error comes randomly so I don't know how to reproduce it. I have added the image from cloud logs

Comment: Where does the log `Inside on Form Submit` come from? Can you show more of you relevant code, well as implement and analyse more logs to see which line exactly gives you the error?

Comment: `const respondentEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();` this line gives me the error. I have narrowed it down.  `Inside on Form Submit` is a console on my form trigger function. I have updated the above code too

Comment: I created a new form, copied your code into a function, installed a trigger that execute that function, and... everything works fine. Can't reproduce neither help you :(

Comment: Yeah that is the problem I'm also not able to reproduce the error but it keeps coming at least once every hour

Comment: if the bug is from Google, you could add try/catch and log the content request somewhere else. At least you don't lose it, and then restart the process you need

Comment: let me try this

Comment: After `const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();` implement a [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) request and see if this solves the issue. PS: Can you retrieve `formResponses` successfully even when `respondentEmail` throws you an error? Can you log e.g. `formResponses[0].getItemResponses()[0].getItem().getTitle()` and verify that it works  even when you get the exception?

Comment: I have tried Sleep function but it did not solved the issue for me. Right now I have again called the onFormSubmit in catch if it fails after sleep of 3 seconds. I will also put console in that thanks for suggestion

Comment: The issue is with your form.  Make a copy and Delete the form. Connect the script to the copy.

Comment: Which line is line 94?

Comment: The issue is intermittent and not easily reproduced. Perhaps it is timing issue related to your use of an async function. Try using a normal function instead of an async function and see if that helps.

Comment: [FormApp.FormResponse.getRespondentEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getrespondentemail) documentation tells that you should replace `if (respondentEmail === "") return false` with `if (!respondentEmail) return false;`.

Comment: Something wrong with the email inputted? Try reproducing it by submitting the exact similar response with the same email that was in the response that caused the error.

Comment: ok let me try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this issue occurs from google and we don’t have much control over it, try delaying the call using Sleep method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the issue is intermittent, you could retry the problematic call with [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). Replace this line:

```js
  const respondentEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
```

...with:

```js
  let respondentEmail;
  try {
    respondentEmail = exponentialBackoff_(() => e.response.getRespondentEmail());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    respondentEmail = '';
  }
```

Here's a simple `exponentialBackoff_()` implementation:

```js
/**
* Calls a closure, retries on failure, and returns the value it gives.
*
* Usage:
*   exponentialBackoff_(myFunction);
*   // ...or:
*   exponentialBackoff_(() => myFunction(param1, param2));
*   // ...or:
*   const result = exponentialBackoff_(() => myFunction(param1, param2));
*   // ...or:
*   const respondentEmail = exponentialBackoff_(() => e.response.getRespondentEmail());
*
* @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff
* @param {Function} action The closure to call.
* @param {Number} maxNumTries Optional. The number of times to retry. Defaults to 5.
* @return {Object} The closure return value.
*/
function exponentialBackoff_(action, maxNumTries = 5) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 29 December 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74952372/13045193
  for (let tryNumber = 1; tryNumber <= maxNumTries; tryNumber++) {
    try {
      return action();
    } catch (error) {
      if (tryNumber >= maxNumTries) {
        throw error;
      }
      Utilities.sleep(2 ** (tryNumber - 1) * 1000);
    }
  }
}
```