# Getting sporadic error when getting the active form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I am once in a while getting this error:

> Jan 5, 2023, 11:03:48 AM  Error   Exception: Failed to  retrieve form
> data. Please wait and try again. at processForm(Code:2:22)

Line 2 is:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
```

Full script

```
function processForm(event) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  Logger.log("Form retrieved " + form)
  var allResponses = form.getResponses();
  var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
  var itemResponses = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
  //const itemResponses = event.response.getItemResponses();
  const propertyAddress = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  Logger.log("Processing address " + propertyAddress);
  // Get the number of units. index 5
  const moreThan200Units = parseInt(itemResponses[5].getResponse(), 10);
  var mainFolder = null;
  if(moreThan200Units > 199) {
    mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xx');
  } else {
    mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('yy');
  }

  var propertyFolder = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(itemResponses[i].getItem().getType())
    if (itemResponses[i].getItem().getType() == "FILE_UPLOAD") {
      if(propertyFolder == null) {
        propertyFolder = mainFolder.createFolder(propertyAddress);
      }
      var ids = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
      for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
        var uploadedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ids[j]);
        Logger.log("Moving file" + uploadedFile + " to " + propertyFolder);
        uploadedFile.moveTo(propertyFolder);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't use the form onFormSubmit much but I do believe that the responses come from the event and not form.  The form in this case is meant for editing I believe.

Comment: What's the error rate that you're seeing?

Comment: Just to be clear, would you please confirm that 1) your function is container-bound to your form, 2) what is the type of trigger ([Open or FormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events)).

Comment: @Daniel 16.67% error rate.

Comment: @Tedinoz 1: I do not know what you mean by "container bound" :) how do I see that? 2: From form - On form submit

Comment: @Tedinoz 1: Under "Project Details" it says "Container". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Related question: [Exception: Failed to retrieve form data. Please wait and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74871628/1330560)