# Exponential Backoff test only tries once

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to test an Exponential Backoff function, but it only appears to Catch once then return.  I'm sure it's something simple, but what am I missing?

EB fn

```js
function tryAgain(action, maxTries = 5) {
    for (let tries = 0; tries < maxTries; tries++) {
      Logger.log(`Try number ${tries}`);
      try {
        return action();
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(`Error caught; trying again: ${e}`);
        if (tries = maxTries) { throw e; };
      }
      Utilities.sleep(2 ** tries * 1000)
    }
  }
```

test fn

```js
function myFunction() {
  tryAgain(testTryAgain);
}

function testTryAgain() {
  Logger.log("test");
  throw "error msg"
}
```

Comment: See [How to reference material written by others](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: The primary issue with your `tryAgain()` function is with `tries = maxTries` which should be an equality test rather than an assignment. Use a linter to avoid typos like that. A secondary issue is that `tries` will never reach `maxTries` because the test `tries < maxTries` prevents the `if()` from being reached.

Comment: thank you, @doubleunary!  I new it was something simple, I just wish it hadn't been so dumb /sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a more reliable exponential backoff implementation, like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  exponentialBackoff_(testTryAgain);
}
```

To supply arguments, use a closure, like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const param = 1;
  const result = exponentialBackoff_(() => testTryAgain(param));
  console.log(result);
}
```

Here is a copy of the `exponentialBackoff_()` function from [Exception: Failed to retrieve form data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74952372/13045193), including full JSDoc and attribution:

```js
/**
* Calls a closure, retries on failure, and returns the value it gives.
*
* Usage:
*   exponentialBackoff_(myFunction);
*   // ...or:
*   exponentialBackoff_(() => myFunction(param1, param2));
*   // ...or:
*   const result = exponentialBackoff_(() => myFunction(param1, param2));
*   // ...or:
*   const respondentEmail = exponentialBackoff_(() => e.response.getRespondentEmail());
*
* @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff
* @param {Function} action The closure to call.
* @param {Number} maxNumTries Optional. The number of times to retry. Defaults to 5.
* @return {Object} The closure return value.
*/
function exponentialBackoff_(action, maxNumTries = 5) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 29 December 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74952372/13045193
  for (let tryNumber = 1; tryNumber <= maxNumTries; tryNumber++) {
    try {
      return action();
    } catch (error) {
      if (tryNumber >= maxNumTries) {
        throw error;
      }
      Utilities.sleep(2 ** (tryNumber - 1) * 1000);
    }
  }
}
```