# Googlesheets check if last execution failed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a trigger that kicks off some code at 2 am each night.

sometimes the code fails due to various reason like network issue, or timing out because the site is busy and responses are slow (make numerous api calls)

I was thinking of putting in a code than runs based on a trigger every 15 minutes, to see if the last execution failed, then run my code again.

Been googling and search stackoverflow, but can't find a starting point on how to achieve this.

Basically I want to know if the last execution (which I can see manually in the executions screen) has a failed or time-out status, if it does I'll kick off my code again.

Comment: Can you implement try / catch?

Comment: Hi, I don't think that would work for networking/timeout issues would it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). You may want to try the [exponentialBackoff_()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74952372/13045193) function, like this:

```js
function myFunctionThatRunsOnATrigger() {
  exponentialBackoff_(myFunctionThatSometimesFails);
}

function myFunctionThatSometimesFails() {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Having a read and trying it out

Does this only allow you to re-run the current function if it fails?

Would it work if I wanted to execute a different function if the current one fails (my process is different functions run in sequence, and I'd need to restart from function 1 upon failure)

Comment: Create a "runner" function that runs the required functions in sequence, and run the runner through `exponentialBackoff_()`.